# Big XML file import to database PHP

Tags: php, xml, database, multithreading, import

I am facing a problem that somehow I don't see the solution to it. I have a XML file that needs to be importet to custom DB structure, when user uploads / imports the file the ajax post is waiting untill the file import is finished, but this could take 5 hours or more I don't know. What is the best way to handle this UI issue.

- I was thinkg about thread uplaod, to split the file in multiple parts and upload each with it's own thread (pthreads, having problems with instalation on centos 7 / PHP 7)
- Or if there is any other way that I could import the file in the background and whenerever the user refreshes the page there would be a status log output so that user would know when the import is finished and if successful.

Comment: The upload takes 5 hours? Or the server-side database processing does?

Comment: use a background job, and email them when it's done.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Yes the server side database processing takes long.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix do you have like any example that I could take a look at.

Comment: @olyar - have you ever setup a cron job for PHP?

Comment: What I would do is setup a PHP script that just takes the filename as the input, and run it -via- the command line or using  `exec` on my GIT I have a class that will do background jobs ( it's designed to use with CodeIgniter ) so it passes the args in the format of   `php pathtophpfile.php arg1/arg2/ag3`  https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/BgProcess.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to run them using a background job ( a detached process ) this way the end user gets a confirmation message right away, and then send an email when the long running task is complete.  Then they don't have to wait for it to finish.  As I mentioned in the comments I have a class I wrote on my git hub for this

https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/BgProcess.php

But it passes the args as a path because it's setup for Code Igniter, so you would have to change that or split the arguments up within your code.

Anyway the basics is similar to running a cron job,  This varies in the implantation depending on the OS of the server.  But on Linux the command is like this

```
 php -f "path/to/phpfile.php" "{args}" > /dev/null &
```

The  `> /dev/null &` part sends the output to null ( throws it away ) and the `&` runs it as a non-blocking process meaning the script starting the command can continue on.  So using an example as this

```
 .. other code before starting background job ..
 exec( 'php -f "path/to/phpfile/xmlProcessor.php" "testXML/2" > /dev/null &');
  .. code to tell user job is started .. this runs right after the call without waiting for that process to finish.
```

Then in xmlProcessor.php you would have this

```
  <?php

         $args = explode('/', $argv[1]);
         $file = $ags[0];
         $user_id = $args[1];
         ... code to process xml 
          ... email user confirmation of completion
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

As I said typically would call it this way,

```
  exec( 'php -f "path/to/phpfile/xmlProcessor.php" "testXML" "2" > /dev/null &');
```

And access them using

```
   $argv[1] // = testXML
   $argv[2] // = 2
```

But because I use this with CI, it does it's routing for me to a special controller and handles all that.  The nice thing about my class is that it should find the PHP executable under most cases, and it has windows compatibility built in ( which was a pain in the ...)

Using that class you would just call it like this

```
 $command = new BgProcess( "path/to/phpfile/xmlProcessor.php", "testXML", 2);

 echo $command;
```

Would output `'php -f "path/to/phpfile/xmlProcessor.php" "testXML/2" > /dev/null &'` after starting the process ( the return is just for debugging )

Basically your running a separate background job with PHP via the command line.

Comment: This looks nice, I'm actualy working in CodeIgniter, and I've never used a cron job ;(

Comment: This is different then a cron job in that you are not using cron, but cron lets you run a background process at an timed interval.  So it's no the same, but experience coding for cron jobs or any CLI ( command line interface ) type scripts would be useful.

Comment: in CI, it would route this to something like `php -f "path/to/CI/index.php" "contoller/method/arg1/arg2.."`  But I have a custom router so I can use multiple controller files in sub-folders ( welcome.php )

Comment: Also for CLI scripts I use a seperate index.php that is outside of the webroot, so it's not accessible from the browser.

Comment: I'm also still using CI version 2 for this, our application is about 4 years old now, and it's to much to refactor it for CI 3

Comment: so for the path i could use base_url(controller/method/arg1/arg2). But I'm having a problem with argv seems like this is no longer support in php versions 5.6  and higher and i'm having a problem that the php executable is not found

Comment: explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, getenv('PATH')) this gets me an empty array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147898/discussion-between-olyar-and-artisticphoenix).

Comment: `For the Notice message, from PHP for argv variable. enable register_argc_argv in you php.ini file.`

Comment: is `PATH_SEPARATOR` defined ? I forget if this was a built in constant or a custom one, it should be "/" on linux.  Also getenv may be dependent on your installation.  As I said you may have to tweek that a bit, it only use it on one server so I am not sure about it's robustness in other environments.

Comment: on Windows you probably haven't set the PATH environmental variable for the php.exe file.  See https://john-dugan.com/add-php-windows-path-variable/